# apt says that I have a held broken package but this package doesn't exist

Tags: linux, apt, gpg-agent

When I'm trying to install the gpg-agent package, I get an error

`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gpg-agent : Depends: libassuan0 (>= 2.5.1) but 2.4.3-2 is to be installed
             Recommends: gnupg (= 2.2.12-1~bpo9+1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

But, when I'm trying to find out it via apt list, I get this result

`root@emmaHost:/home/emma# apt list libassum0
Listing... Done
root@emmaHost:/home/emma#`

Earlier I was trying to install gpg from source files, but i didn't have some required libs, the sourse code of witch I downloaded, and try to install, and among them was that (libassum) lib.

How to correctly fix this error? Thx

Comment: When I'm installing required version of libassum, I'm get error 'held broken package' anyway

Comment: What distribution of Linux are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Spot difference

```
libassuan0
libassum0
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I have learned in the past about dependencies is that often you will need to search for the develop libraries. Depending on your system they end with -dev or -devel

Most header files in those libraries have logic to switch to a different version.

If you are building from source you can go into the configure file and manually change the version requirement *Just remember what you did and make a back up of the original)

Another point, is that each distribution has a certain gcc version attached to it. I had to edit some of the source files when working with source files that was requiring an older gcc version.

I would give that a shot and see if that resolves your issue.